# Anylogic Model Font Size

Tags: font-size, anylogic

I opened my model this morning and it appears the model wide font size on all the blocks has increased significantly. Is there somewhere in the model that I can address the entire models font size for all the blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean the font size showing during design-time, i.e. in the AnyLogic development environment, right?

This is driven by your system resolution and font settings, change those and restart your machine.

The runtime model fontsizes are defined by the font objects and your browser zoom settings, so maybe you changed those...

Comment: oh, also maybe you are using a different monitor with different DPI, that has an impact.

Comment: Thank you, it was a system issue. The actual run time font size had not changed.